# How to get the values dynamically added controls in other parts of the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a method that creates textboxes depending on the number of parameters values that the user has to enter.And its working fine. The problem is that when the user clicks Ok i want to take the value that the user entered in these textboxes and replace them in a string. When am searching these textboxes to get the text value from them am not finding them. How do i get these values to continue my project? the code is:

```
 protected void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbHeader.Text = "Template Designer";
        divQueryBuilder.Visible = false;
        divTemplateDesigner.Visible = false;
        divFloating.Visible = true;

        if (txtQuery.Text.Contains("WHERE") || txtQuery.Text.Contains("where")||txtQuery.Text.Contains("Where"))
        {
            string[] splitter=new string[10];
            splitter[0]="Where";
            splitter[1]="WHERE";
            splitter[2]="where";
            splitter[3]="AND";
            splitter[4] = "and";
            splitter[5] = "And";
            string[] condition=txtQuery.Text.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int numberOfParameters = condition.Length - 1;
            string[] Condition1 =null;
            Label[] newLabel = new Label[10];
            TextBox[] txtBox = new TextBox[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParameters; i++)
            {
                string lbValue="lbValue";
                string lbID=lbValue+i;
                string txtValue = "txtValue";
                string txtID = txtValue + i;
                HtmlGenericControl genericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("br/");
                Condition1 = condition[i + 1].Split('[', ']');
                newLabel[i] = new Label();
                txtBox[i] = new TextBox();
                newLabel[i].ID=lbID;
                newLabel[i].Text = Condition1[1];
                txtBox[i].ID = txtID;

                td2.Controls.Add(newLabel[i]);
                td2.Controls.Add(genericControl);
                td2.Controls.Add(txtBox[i]);
                td2.Controls.Add(genericControl);
                txtBox[i].EnableViewState = true;
            }
        }
    }

 private bool ControlExistence(string lbID)
    {
        try
        {
            td2.FindControl(lbID);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // GetTextBoxValues();
        string[] splitter1 = new string[10];
        splitter1[0] = "Where";
        splitter1[1] = "WHERE";
        splitter1[2] = "where";
        splitter1[3] = "AND";
        splitter1[4] = "and";
        splitter1[5] = "And";
        string[] condition = txtQuery.Text.Split(splitter1, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int numberOfParameters = condition.Length - 1;
        string[] splitter = new string[4];
        splitter[0] = "[";
        splitter[1] = "]";
        splitter[2] = "'";

        string[] queryBoxValue = txtQuery.Text.Split(splitter,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < queryBoxValue.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!queryBoxValue[i].Contains("?"))
            {
                query.Append(queryBoxValue[i]);
                query.Append(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < numberOfParameters; counter1++)
                {
                    string txtValue = "txtValue";
                    string txtID = txtValue + counter1;
                    if (ControlExistence(txtID))
                    {
                        TextBox box = (TextBox)td2.FindControl(txtID);
                        string b = box.Text;
                        //txtBox.ID = txtID;
                    }
                    txtBox.Text = "'" + txtBox.Text + "'";
                    queryBoxValue[i] = queryBoxValue[i].Replace(queryBoxValue[i], txtBox.Text);
                    query.Append(queryBoxValue[i]);
                }

            }
        }
        string fireQuery = query.ToString();
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(fireQuery, conn);
        tab = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(tab);
        if (tab.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] tempString = txtTemplate.Text.Split(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j < tempString.Length; j++)
            {
                if (tempString[j].StartsWith("["))
                {
                    txtPreview.Text = txtTemplate.Text.Replace(tempString[j], tab.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        divFloating.Visible = false;
        divQueryBuilder.Visible = false;
        divTemplateDesigner.Visible = true;
    }
```

Please help. This has become a blocker for me.

Comment: Look at your generated html source code what IDs are actually used. I'd guess you have old id-ing style or predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a list of the added controls and use it when needed.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParameters; i++)
        {
            // ...

            td2.Controls.Add(newLabel[i]);
            td2.Controls.Add(genericControl);
            td2.Controls.Add(txtBox[i]);
            td2.Controls.Add(genericControl);

            addedTextBoxes.Add(txtBox[i]);

            // ...
        }
```

And then from another part of your code:

```
var values = addedTextBoxes.Select(tb => tb.Text).ToList();

foreach (var txtBox in addedTextBoxes)
{
    // ...
}
```

etc...

Comment: Wont it be set to null when the autopostback happens?

Comment: If there's a PostBack, you can add params to the request instead of saving into a list. You can call them ("txtBox" + i)

Comment: i dint get your suggestion. Can u please elaborate?

Comment: Add txtBox's text to the request Params, with a name appropriate for the txtBox. Access the params as you usually access params by request.Params["paramName"];